# How to reset the yakuake configuration on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, themes, skin, yakuake

I've installed a skin in yakuake drop down terminal (emulator based on KDE Konsole), but the configuration button disappeared. like this:
[YAKUAKE KONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQX9e.jpg).

I reinstall it twice but always the same problem, I try to install new skin (tar.gz), but when I extract files "./configure" file doesn't exist, can someone help me please?

Comment: A simpler solution to this; `ctrl` + `shift` + `,` (comma, not period) will bring up Yakuake configuration, and allow you to change the skin back to one with a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about your other yakuake configuration you can try to do is to purge instead of reinstall.

Which skin caused this problem btw?
You can try to manually remove the skin here ~/.kde/share/apps/yakuake

On Gnome here : 
~/.config/yakuakerc

Comment: thanks so much Mr Sougata , i deleted skin caused that problem from ~/.kde/share/apps/yakuake :)

Comment: Glad to have helped Khalil Meg